# How to obtain such 3D surface plot with Matlab

Tags: matlab-figure, undocumented-behavior

A working example with matlab's built-in `peaks` or similar function  would be OK;

1. two different axes (size) planes have different color;
2. color effects similar to `contour3` but overlapped with `mesh/surf`
3. contour plot in the third(ground) axis plane;

I tried in the documented properties of axes handle but failed. Maybe some undocumented features are needed in order to obtain the such a figure?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a contour plot (point 3) by creating a new axis:

```
[xz,y,z] = peaks;

f = figure;
[~, hc]     =   contourf(xz, y, z);
a1          =   gca;
a2          =   axes('Parent', f, 'Position', a1.Position);

hs          =   surf(xz, y, z, 'Parent', a2);

a1.Color    =   'none';
a2.Color    =   'none';

a1.ZLim     =   [0 1];
a2.ZLim     =   [-9 9];

a1.XTick    =   [];
a1.YTick    =   [];
a1.ZTick    =   [];

a1.Box      =   'off';
a2.Box      =   'off';

% Call after setting desired view on a2 (surf plot)
a1.View     =   a2.View;
```

Produces this on MATLAB 2014b:
[image: Contour and surface plot]